# Retrieve parameters from custom validation object

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

I have basic custom `validation rule`. In

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    foreach ($parameters as $key)
    {
        if ( ! empty(Input::get($key)) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have my rule defined. I, although need to retrieve `parameters` from the `rule` but the `passes` method does not provide it as an `argument`.

If I would use the style `Validator:extends...` that provides `4 arguments: $attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator`. Then I could use the `parameters` easily, unfortunatelly I have to use this way.

**EDIT:**

To clear the question. I want to retrieve the `parameters of the rule`, like so in other way of coding it:
`'not_empty:user_id'`. The array of values behind the colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:---

The custom rule object is simply an object. If you want to pass it any more parameters you can in it's constructor:

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required', new MyCustomRule('param', true, $foo)],
]);
```

Then save those and use them in your `passes` function.

```
public function __construct($myCustomParam){
    $this->myCustomParam = $myCustomParam;
}
```

Then in your passes function use:

```
$this->myCustomParam
```

Comment: Ofcourse you can type hint them, smart. However I think you want `$this->request->input($key);` to retrieve other input data instead of rout parameters.

Comment: @AlexBouma i read it as trying to access a route parameter... now that I read it again im not sure either of us got his question exactly right. Is he referring to passing params into a validation rule?

Comment: @Epsilon47 I think Jeff and I both misunderstood your question :) could you clarify it?

Comment: @Jeff that's it. I was considering such possibility. But I did not want to re-invent the wheel again if there is some built-in method to do so. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way is to retrieve it from the request when using rule objects.

For example:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    foreach ($parameters as $key) {
        // Or using \Request::input($key) if you want to use the facade
        if (!empty(request()->input($key)) { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
 }
```